# Python: Drop duplicate element within nested list, if element is an element within another nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists, drop-duplicates

How do we deduplicate elements within nested lists based on the elements within another nested list?
Or, does it make more sense to iterate through a column and drop duplicates based on a list of elements in another column?

```
Column 1
R1 = [foo, bar, baz, qux,] 
R2 = [Cat, Dog, Frog, Bird]
R3 = [Salad, Potato, Pizza, Soda

Column 2
R1 = [bar, quuz, quux, qux]
R2 = [Fish, Dog, Cow]
R3 = [Potato, Milk, Apple, Pizza]
```

I only care to keep elements unique to `listB` and order does not matter

```
Final Column
R1 = [quuz, quux]
R2 = [Fish, Cow]
R3 = [Milk, Apple]
```

An actual list looks like this and includes the following characters: \ , ()

```
[Youth Counselor / Worker, Nutrition / Dietetic Technician,Mathematician,Tailor / Seamstress,Librarian]
```

I must protect each element as a string so a flat list wont work in this case

Answer (score 3):

If order doesn't matter:

- use [set operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) on each pair of nested lists. Subtracting two sets produces a new set with only the elements from the first that don't appear in the second.
- Use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up the nested lists from your two input lists.
- If your output must consist of nested lists again, convert the result of the set operation back to a list, with `list()`
- Use a list comprehension to process each pair of nested lists, creating a new list with the results.

This can be expressed as a one-liner with:

```
[list(set(b) - set(a)) for a, b in zip(listA, listB)]
```

You can drop the `list(...)` call if nested sets in your output is acceptable:

```
[set(b) - set(a) for a, b in zip(listA, listB)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> listA = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%']]
>>> listB = [['E', 'A', 'T', 'F', 'W'], [5, 6, 8, 2, 9], ['@', '^', '&', '#', '*']]
>>> [list(set(b) - set(a)) for a, b in zip(listA, listB)]
[['W', 'F', 'T'], [8, 9, 6], ['^', '&', '*']]
>>> [set(b) - set(a) for a, b in zip(listA, listB)]  # without list(...)
[{'W', 'F', 'T'}, {8, 9, 6}, {'^', '&', '*'}]
```

If you change your mind and decide that order *does* matter for the output, then:

- Only convert each nested list in `listA` to a set, *once*, for faster containment testing. `value in listobject` has to iterate through `listobject` each time, whereas `value in setobject` uses hashing to test for containment in O(1) (constant) time.
- Loop over the values in a given nested list in `listB` and test the value against the matching set from `listA`, keeping only the values that don't appear in the corresponding set. Use a list comprehension for this.
- You could use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to handle converting the `listA` nested lists to sets as you pair up the lists. This then helps avoid creating a new set each time you test a value from the nested list from `listB`.

So a one-liner that preserves input ordering is:

```
[[v for v in nested_b if v not in set_a] for set_a, nested_b in zip(map(set, listA), listB)]
```

The `zip()` function pairs up the sets produced from `listA` (via `map(set, listA)`) and the nested lists from `listB` so we can use them together each iteration of the outermost list comprehension. The nested list comprehension then filters the values for each nested list:

```
>>> [[v for v in nested_b if v not in set_a] for set_a, nested_b in zip(map(set, listA), listB)]
[['T', 'F', 'W'], [6, 8, 9], ['^', '&', '*']]
```

Comment: Apologies, but I may have confused the question by the format of my example lists.
                 `[Youth Counselor / Worker, Nutrition / Dietetic Technician,Mathematician,Tailor / Seamstress,Librarian]`    This is a more accurate list of what I'm working with. I tried this method and it separates my elements into single characters and then drops duplicates.         `[['D','b', 'A','h','i',',','E','v',`]]

Comment: @NathanTriepke: That's not a Python list. If you are working with a Pandas dataframe and series, post a new question with a [clear example dataframe in the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: @NathanTriepke: the output you see suggests you *don't have nested lists*.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sets`, You can do:

```
listA = [["A","B","C","D","E"],[1,2,3,4,5],["!","@","#","$","%"]]
listB = [["E","A","T","F","W"],[5,6,8,2,9],["@","^","&","#","*"]]


print([list(set(listB[i]).difference(set(listA[i]))) for i in range(len(listB))])
```

Gives me:

```
[['F', 'W', 'T'], [8, 9, 6], ['^', '&', '*']]
```

Note: it will change the order of list.

> Edit:
>
> Or as @user3483203 suggested, more reliable solution than this will be:
>
> ```
> [[list(b - a) for a, b in zip(map(set, listA), map(set, listB))]
> ```

Comment: `[[list(b - a) for a, b in zip(map(set, listA), map(set, listB))]` might be a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to check by index of lists

```
result_list = []
for listA_nest,listB_nest zip(listA,listB):
    result_list.append(list(filter(lambda listB_el: listB_el not in listA_nest ,listB_nest))
```

Something like that should work, there is probagbly a better solution.

One line solution:

```
result_list = [list(filter(lambda listB_el: listB_el not in set(listA_nest) ,listB_nest)) for listA_nest,listB_nest in zip(listA,listB)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are checking corresponding lists in A and B, you'll probably want [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to keep them together, and you can use the `in` method to check membership:

```py
listFinal = []
for l1, l2 in zip(listA, listB):
    l = [x for x in l2 if x not in l1]
    listFinal.append(l)

[['T', 'F', 'W'], [6, 8, 9], ['^', '&', '*']]
```

Though the faster way would be to use a `set`, which allows you to quickly deduplicate collections and test for membership in O(1), rather than O(N):

```py
listFinal = []

for l1, l2 in zip(listA, listB):
    # set subtraction here will remove all elements present in l1 from l2
    l = set(l2) - set(l1)
    listFinal.append(list(l))

[['T', 'F', 'W'], [8, 9, 6], ['*', '&', '^']]
```

Or, in one line if you prefer

```py
listFinal = [list(set(l2) - set(l1)) for l1, l2 in zip(listA, listB)]
```

To show how zip works:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]

for x, y in zip(a, b):
    print(x, y)

1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

It will generate groups of corresponding elements for each iterable passed to it.

Set subtraction:

```py
a = set('a', 'b', 'c')
b = set('b', 'c', 'd')

a - b

{'a'}
```